# Backbone View Being Initialized on Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to post to a spring endpoint with this -

```
  _checkForInfiniteScrolling:=>
    query = @options.query
    scrollElement = @searchResultContainerElem[0]
    prog = (scrollElement.scrollTop + scrollElement.offsetHeight)/scrollElement.scrollHeight
    if (prog > 0.8) and !@endData and scrollElement.scrollTop > 0
      console.log("hitting ajax")
      @getMoreResults(query)

  getMoreResults:(query)=>
    longitude = query.get("longitude")
    latitude = query.get("latitude")
    if (longitude!="" && latitude !="")
      @findMoreLocationPlates(query)
    else
      @findMorePartialPlates(query)

  findMorePartialPlates:(query)=>
    console.log("in find more partial plates")
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: query,
      url: "someUrl"
      success: @_appendNewResults
      })
```

However, it is calling this function which exists in another model -

```
  loadSearchHistory:=>
    console.log("load search being called")
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "anotherUrl",
      success:@_searchHistoryLoaded
      });

  _searchHistoryLoaded:(data)=>
    console.log("wtf?")
    searchHistoryView = new SearchHistory(pastSearches:data)
```

The weird thing is, the _searchHistoryLoaded is being called and then loadSearchHistory is being called, which should never happen because _searchHistoryLoaded is never called from another function.

To help, this is the stack at the error -

```
  PlateSearchQuery._searchHistoryLoaded (-search.js:78)
(anonymous function) (-search-results.js:4)
jQuery.extend.param.add (jquery-1.7.1.js:7601)
buildParams (jquery-1.7.1.js:7658)
jQuery.extend.param (jquery-1.7.1.js:7621)
jQuery.extend.ajax (jquery-1.7.1.js:7467)
handleAjax (jquery.mockjax.js:469)
PlateResultsView.findMorePartialPlates (-search-results.js:227)
(anonymous function) (-search-results.js:4)
PlateResultsView.getMoreResults (-search-results.js:221)
(anonymous function) (-search-results.js:4)
PlateResultsView._checkForInfiniteScrolling (-search-results.js:210)
(anonymous function) (-search-results.js:4)
jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery-1.7.1.js:3256)
$event.dispatch (jquery.event.drag-2.2.js:374)
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle (jquery-1.7.1.js:2875)
```

Admittedly, it is probably difficult for anyone to solve this, advice on how to debug it would be appreciated as well.

EDIT-

Made a mistake with the trace - I've now put up the call stack that is there when I am at console.log("wtf?)

Comment: check it now- think it's more relevant

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fairly simple, when doing ajax calls, data should be a JSON object NOT a Backbone object.